# What does "gone rogue" mean in this context?

Tags: phrase-meaning

This is from [a *New York Times* article](https://www.nytimes.com/2020/01/11/opinion/sunday/meghan-markle-harry-royal-family.html) :

> The ghost of Diana **gone rogue** animates the fractured fairy tale of
> Meghan and Harry, and their intemperate attempt to upend centuries of
> starchy rules and break away from the Firm.

I looked up the adjective 'rogue' in [the Merriam-Webster dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/rogue) :

> 1 : resembling or suggesting a rogue elephant especially in being
> isolated, aberrant, dangerous, or uncontrollable
>
> 3 : of or being a nation whose leaders defy international law or norms
> of international behavior rogue states

I am curious which of the following "**gone rogue**" means in this context.

1. seen as rebelling against the established norms and expectations of the royal family
2. passed away in a state of isolation from the royal family

Comment: From that small quote, it's not possible to tell what the writer means. It could literally mean that the narrator character is the ghost of Princess Diana rebelling against the Royal Family, or it could mean that the style of the narrator resembles Diana, but is not following the norms of the Royal Family.

Comment: @gotube Thank you very much. You mean "gone" does not mean 'dead'. Right?

Comment: It definitely does not mean "dead". A ghost is already dead. It means "turned" or "become".

Comment: @gotube Thank you very much. Since I feel like I have obtained the answer I wanted completely from you, is it okay for me to delete this question?

Comment: No, ellse, we only delete questions that don't belong on this site because they're spam or very rude. Good questions with satisfactory answers stay here forever so that other people can read them later and benefit. I'll put my comments as an answer, and if you like, you can give them an upvote and/or check mark. That's the normal way to resolve a good question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From that small quote, it's not possible to tell what the writer means. It could literally mean that the narrator character is the ghost of Princess Diana rebelling against the Royal Family, or it could mean that the style of the narrator resembles Diana, but is not following the norms of the Royal Family.

Regardless, "gone" definitely does not mean "dead". A ghost is already dead. It means "turned" or "become".

Comment: What author? The reporting/er author or the creator of the animation? I personally think it is very clear. It's the ghost who is being described as going rogue.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: @Lambie Sorry? I didn't say anything about the author. If the ghost of Diana is the actual narrator in the story, I don't know that because the article is behind a paywall. I'm allowing for the possibility that "the ghost of Diana gone rogue" metaphorically describes the narrative style.

Comment: Sorry, I meant writer.

Answer (score 0):

"The ghost of Diana has gone rogue."

**Go rogue** is an idiom which means a person is operating outside the official capacity he or she is supposed to be operating in. It is a term used by spies to mean they are no longer doing their jobs but have started acting outside the boundaries of those jobs.

***Here, it is Diana's ghost, used by the author of this piece on the animation, which is the representation of the princess that has gone rogue***. **Basically, the ghost is doing stuff that was not in the purview of the real princess.**

Comment: Thank you very much.